# How to stop WDL pipeline make duplicate running results

Tags: duplicates, wdl

I am recently using WDL pipeline to build the bioinformatics pipeline for our facility.

The pipeline could run successfully. However, when I re-run the pipeline, it will always restart, reprocess everything and then create a new results in a separate folder.

Please check the screenshot below:

[image]

So the phenomenon, explanation, and what I expect could be summarized below
1: phenomenon:
When we trigger the same WDL pipeline 5 times, 5 new full-set results will be created (the random folders as shown in the screenshot) by the pipeline.

2: explanation
Actually, the oldest random folder "e5e79fc1-e3ff-4b63-ba9d-ca1151b892fa" already contains all successful running results.

3: What I expect
No matter how many times the WDL pipeline be triggered, once there is a successful running results existed in the root directory, the WDL pipeline should simply stop automatically and do nothing.

I used to use snakemake to build the pipeline, and snakemake will simply stop if all results are been existed. I do hope WDL could doing the job in the same way.

May I know how to let WDL pipeline stop automatically when the successful running results are existed in the root directory? Please help.

Thank you so much

Comment: If you are using cromwell, you might want to have a look at this: https://cromwell.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cromwell_features/CallCaching/